Amazon SP API - which permission am I missing to create a feed?
I am following the use case guide for SP feeds.
I am able to create a document and upload XML to it without problems.
However I am unable to use the createFeed (POST /feeds/2021-06-30/feeds) endpoint. I am sending what should be a valid body, and I have proper header, but I am still getting 403.
curl --location 'https://sellingpartnerapi-eu.amazon.com/feeds/2021-06-30/feeds' \
--header 'x-amz-access-token: {token which worked to createDocument}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
"feedType": "POST_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_DATA",
"marketplaceIds": [ "A1PA6795UKMFR9" ],
"inputFeedDocumentId": "{feed Id I got from createDocument}"
}'

And the error message I get is not super helpful:
{
  code: 'Unauthorized',
  message: 'Access to the resource is forbidden',
  details: ''
}

My roles are

Pricing
Inventory and Order Tracking (this one should be the one, no?)
Product Listing

Any help with what am I doing wrong or which permissions am I missing?

Your request seems ok, but:

POST request type is missing
double check your inputFeedDocumentId
ensure your application has the Direct to Consumer Shipping (Restricted) role. As written here, it is mandatory in order to push a POST_ORDER_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT_DATA feed.


curl implies POST, when there is --data present. I missed that I need BOTH Direct to Consumer Shipping AND Inventory and Product tracking. I applied already, let's see how it goes.
